# sql oracle sum group

Tags: sql, oracle

The SQL I coded gives me the following output:

```
column1  column2    column3

50       RedCar     8
50       RedCar     8
50       RedCar     8
40       BlueCar    8
20       YellowCar  8
80       WhiteCar   8
50       RedCar     8
```

The final result I am looking for is:

```
column1  column2      column3

50       RedCar       32
40       BlueCar      8
20       YellowCar    8
80       Whitecar     8
```

**What should happen in text:**

My SQL finds all rows with the same **ID** in `column1` and makes one row from it summing up the numbers in `column3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `group by`clause with `sum` function as below

```
select column1,column2,sum(column3) as column3
from tab
group by column1,column2
```