# How to group by one col and sum another col values for each group? - with SQL, Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

it's a simple one (I guess).
There's a table:

```
COL_NAME     QTY

alpha        3
alpha        5
alpha        1
beta         4
beta         2
gamma        1
gamma        1
gamma        1
gamma        2
```

I'd like to group it and order by COL_NAME, with sums of QTY for each group.
How would I do that?

```
COL_NAME     QTY

alpha        9
beta         6
gamma        5
```

Comment: Show us your current query attempt!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql oracle sum group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303824/sql-oracle-sum-group)

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
SELECT col_name, SUM(qty)
  FROM <table_name>
 GROUP BY col_name
 ORDER BY col_name;
```

Comment: sorry guys. I wanted to make it simple and turned out incomplete. Newbie's mistake. Still, that you for you answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select col_name, sum(qty)
from tablename
group by col_name
```

Comment: @AndyVincent:- Then you need to provide more details. The above answer is for the example or details provided presently.

Comment: Post the actual issue you want solved, then people can solve it for you.

Comment: @RahulTripathi , sorry guys. I wanted to make it simple and turned out incomplete. Newbie's mistake. Still, that you for you answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
    SELECT COL_NAME, SUM(QTY) FROM TableNameHere GROUP BY COL_NAME
```

Comment: I'm not sure Oracle can handle [ ] identifiers?

Comment: Remove the `[]` and use double quotes `""` if you must.

Comment: Actually i am using SQL Server, but that does not matter for me guys, i did not yet try coding in oracle so i am not sure to those rules in oracle.. but what matters to me is the logic for the question ask above, if the brackets [] can't be use in oracle then, it can be easily ignore by the person who ask the question above.

Comment: @Japongskie is it so difficult to remove them then from your answer? It may not matter to you but other people (future readers) will get the wrong idea if they see your answer - for a question that is tagged with `oracle`. You don't need brackets in SQL Server either if your tables and columns are named without special characters.

Comment: My apologies for putting brackets awhile ago, since i test the script in sql server. Thanks for correcting me :)